# Linq to XML casting XML file to custom object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm using Linq to XML to read in an XML file and as part of this I'd like to create an object.  My object looks like this:

```
    public class Address
    {
        public string AccountRef { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        // more stuff here
    }
```

And my XML file looks like this:

```
<rows>
    <row>
      <FIELD NAME="AccountRef">1234</FIELD>
      <FIELD NAME="AddressLine1">My Address Line 1</FIELD>
      <FIELD NAME="AddressLine2">My Address Line 2</FIELD>
    </row>
    <row>
      <FIELD NAME="AccountRef">5678</FIELD>
      <FIELD NAME="AddressLine1">My Address Line 3</FIELD>
      <FIELD NAME="AddressLine2">My Address Line 4</FIELD>
    </row>
</rows>
```

In terms of code, I've tried various things, but at present I have the following which returns the correct number of rows in the format:

```
<row><FIELD NAME="AccountRef">1234</FIELD><FIELD>...rest of data</row>
<row><FIELD NAME="AccountRef">5678</FIELD><FIELD>...rest of data</row>
```

The code that does this is:

```
var results = (from d in document.Descendants("row")
               select d).ToList();
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is something like:

```
var results = (from d in document.Descendants("row")
               select new Address
               {
                   AccountRef = d.Attribute("AccountRef").Value,
                   AddressLine1 = d.Attribute("AddressLine1").Value
               }).ToList();
```

Obviously because my nodes are the same (FIELD NAME) that won't work, so does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to retrive field names and values before creating objects

```
var results = document.Descendants("row")
    .Select(row=>row.Elements("FIELD").ToDictionary(x=>x.Attribute("NAME").Value, x=>x.Value))
    .Select(d=>new Address 
       {                    
        AccountRef = d["AccountRef"],
        AddressLine1 = d["AddressLine1"],
        AddressLine2 = d["AddressLine2"],
       });
```

check [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hDzBEj)